# Load of Transactional Replication at the Publisher

Tags: sql-server, transactional-replication

I would like to enable replication on my SQL Server , as per the [Document](https://nanopdf.com/download/transactional-replication-performance-tuning-and-optimization_pdf) , the load on Server as a Remote Distributor is less(i.e. 8-10% for insert/update in publisher)  when compared with load on SQL Server as a  Local Distributor (i.e bieng Publisher as well as Distributer) (16-25% for insert/update).[Page no : 11]

Also The [Document](https://nanopdf.com/download/transactional-replication-performance-tuning-and-optimization_pdf) (related to  MSSQL  Server 2000) mentions the cost under stress conditions can be as low as 8-10% when using a remote Distributor, and somewhat higher when using a local Distributor , does this hold good for MSSQL 2017 also?
Why I ask this is , I am  planning to make my SQL server as Local Distributor because of my current limitations.
Should I go ahead with my plan or are there any serious Drawbacks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQL Server 2000 is a version from ages ago, that I wouldn't necessarily follow most documentation on best practices for it when dealing with a newer version, such as SQL Server 2017.

Anecdotally, I've been using Transactional Replication for the last 10 years for instances running SQL Server 2008 R2 up to instances running SQL Server 2019 currently, and I've always ran the Distributor on the Publisher server. I've never had any noticeable issues as a result of doing this. I've used it with some fairly busy servers that had a *good amount* of data being replicated across them.

If that is your only option for implementing replication on your servers, then I'd say try it. If you notice adverse performance issues as a result of doing it, then you can disable the replication jobs or drop the Publications. But in my opinion, I'd say low risk of having any tangible issues from running the Distributor on the Publisher server.

Comment: Lots of 20-year-old performance worries are less important than they once were.  I only recommend remote distribution when your publisher is _already_ overloaded and you don't dare add additional load.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft Appreciate the reassurance I haven't been doing it wrong all these years. 